# iOS : How do I slide a list item to expose commands (w/ storyboards)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uistoryboard

I just started iOS development (I've been web dev for 6+ years) and I'm struggling with understanding how to build my UI beyond the default elements.

I feel like I started at kind of an awkward time. The resources I can find on creating a custom UI forgo the use of storyboards. Yet Xcode5 seems to force the use of storyboards (granted it's in beta so this may change).

While my current goal is to make list items slide over to expose custom actions (similar to mailbox, cobook, and countless other apps), really what I'm asking is for good resources on creating more custom UI's while still using storyboards that will lead me in the direction I need to go in order to do that.

Any help is appreciated, I've been desperately fighting the urge to take the easy way out and just use PhoneGap.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this guide.  In it they show how to make UITableViewCells with horizontal pan gestures so you can create the sort of effect that you are looking for.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/21842/how-to-make-a-gesture-driven-to-do-list-app-part-13

It uses a .xib file (I agree with you about the degree to which people using xib files in tutorials is incredibly annoying when storyboards seem to be the direction Apple is going in).  However, you can make a UITableViewController in the storyboard.  I would mostly use this in order to learn how to make custom UITableViewCells that can then be used in any sort of UITableView.  You simply need to select the cell in the tableview, make the class of the cell the type of UITableViewCell you want (under the "Show Identity Inspector") and then make it the class of your custom UITableViewCell.  Then when you call dequeueCellWithIdentifier, make sure the identifier is the same as the cell in the storyboard, and also cast the cell to your custom type like so...

```
 MySlidingTableViewCell * cell = (MySlidingTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

And make sure you `#import` the class for the cell.